# Not able to Get Final Result in Textbox23

Tags: excel-2013, vba6

I need Code to Get Final Result in Textbox23 after updating below list of textbox and combobx

Details As Below

If LME_Data.ComboBox1.Value = "SHORT" And LME_Data.ComboBox2.Value = "HEDGE POSITION CREATED" And LME_Data.TextBox14.Value > 0 And LME_Data.TextBox16.Value > 0 Then
Result = (LME_Data.TextBox12.Value * (LME_Data.TextBox14.Value - LME_Data.TextBox16.Value)) - LME_Data.TextBox22.Value - LME_Data.TextBox21.Value
ElseIf LME_Data.ComboBox1.Value = "LONG" And LME_Data.ComboBox2.Value = "HEDGE POSITION CREATED" And LME_Data.TextBox14.Value > 0 And LME_Data.TextBox16.Value > 0 Then
Result = (LME_Data.TextBox12.Value * (LME_Data.TextBox16.Value - LME_Data.TextBox14.Value)) - LME_Data.TextBox22.Value - LME_Data.TextBox21.Value
Else
Result = 0
End If

```
LME_Data.TextBox23.Value = Format(Result, "$0.00")
```

Details of All Textbox
Textbox12 Qty
Textbox14 Entry Price
Textbox16 Exit Price
Textbox21 Entry Commission
Textbox22 Exit Commission

Once all textbox and Combobox Updated
I Need Result in Textbox23
and where to Past this code